# wrapping an href around the result of a sql query and making it clickable?

Tags: php, html, sql

In the report_path field I'm trying to make the image path clickable and delivers the user to the image.

```
$query = ("select 
        a.id as id,
        a.result, 
        a.result_date, 
        a.created_at, 
        b.employee as 'Created By',
        case
            when a.in_range='1' then 'IN' else 'OUT'
        end as in_range, 
        case when a.fax='1' then 'YES' else 'NO' end + ' | ' +
        case when a.email= '1' then 'YES' else 'NO' end as 'Pending<br>Fax | Email',
        report_path as '<a href='' + url + ''>report_path</a>',
        result
    from " . table('inrult') . " a
    left outer join " . table('emp') . " b on a.created_by=b.id
    where a.patient_id={$patient->hex} and (a.inactive is null or a.inactive=0) order by result_date desc");
```

It's not exactly working the way I figured. What am i doing wrong?

inspect element is showing the table row event link and not the field event link.

```
<td onclick="go2(&quot;index.php?ae/nic/edit&amp;_id=ACS00&amp;id=5&quot;);">_INR\5_2013-03-15.pdf</td>
```

so when i click anywhere on that row it goes to the above link but i'm not able to specify a different link for a particular field in the table... i hope that makes more sense.

Comment: It would help to tell us what's actually happening, not just "it's not working."

Comment: well, the image path is showing up in the results but the whole row is a clickable event ... so i'm trying to break that particular field into it's own clickable event.

Comment: How is it "not working exactly"? What error messages are you getting? Also, why are you embedding HTML in your SQL? Do not mix presentation (i.e. the HTML) with data logic (the SQL). You can add the HTML trivially when you retrieve the data within your PHP code.

Comment: Yes, as posted above i'm mixing html inside my sql query. I would assume i'm not escaping the html right..

Comment: This really seems like logic you should be handling closer to the display layer of your application not in the query itself. Why would you not generate this HTML in PHP?

Comment: I agree with Dai, a more common approach would be to get the values for the fields, and then use PHP processing to create the HTML. It's more flexible and makes your code clearer. There's no reason what you're trying to do shouldn't be possible, though.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the HTML source of your rendered page? That should make it easy to see whether it's generating the HTML you intended it to or not. If it's still unclear, edit your post and show us the HTML you end up with.

Comment: Rendering HTML in SQL has been known to be a Very Bad Idea.